# How to edit sales_order AdminHtml template

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-enterprise

i want to edit sales_order listing view to add new column but i can not find that template to edit.

i want to edit .phtml file not Block

this is url that i want to edit on it

http://localhost/ProjectName/index.php/admin/sales_order/

[image]

Comment: The admin grids do not work as you think they do. They all use the same PHTML templates, so to add columns to a specific grid, you need to modify the block behavior for this grid. This is best done with an observer.

Comment: (see answer by Vladimir Kerkhoff in the linked duplicate)

Comment: but where is the code which i loop in orders to add my new value

Comment: It does not work like that. Please read the example I gave you carefully.

Comment: ok i read it and unterstand it .
i created marketplace that allows customer to add product from front end and then i want to list for this customer orders for his product
`$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
  $customer_id = $customerData->getId();
  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');   
  $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
   array('attribute'=>'customer_id','eq'=>$customer_id)
  )); 
  $ids=array();
  foreach ($collection as $product) { 
   $ids[]=$product->getId();
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the `sales_order_grid` block in your config.xml file in order to add new column in order listing.

```
<sales_order_grid>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
```

Then create above class in your module & extend it from - `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`

Under `_prepareColumns()` function add your new column & value.

Hope this will help you.